# How to download an older branch of Chromium from Git using gclient?

Tags: git, chromium

I need to build an older version that still supports NPAPI to run the Java Plugin but I can't seem to find the correct syntax to pull it, here's my .glient which pulls the latest revision:

```
solutions = [
  {
    "managed": False,
    "name": "src",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git",
    "custom_deps": {},
    "deps_file": ".DEPS.git",
    "safesync_url": "",
  },
]
```

And to sync I would use:

```
gclient sync
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [specific page on chromium.org](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches) that explains how to check out the source of a specific release. You should follow the instructions there.

Comment: That should probably work but I haven't tested, it was a nightmare dealing with it and I just gave up on the idea.